# i am trying to get FACEBOOK COVER via graph API, but i cant.

Tags: facebook, api, graph

```
try {   
    $requestCover = $fb->get('me?fields=cover'); //getting user Cover
     $requestProfileCover=$fb->get('/me');  
//   $cover = $requestCover->getGraphUser();        
//  $profile = $requestProfileCover->getGraphUser();    
     } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo ' error: ' . $e->getMessage();         
    exit;   
     }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {            
     echo 'Facebook SDK error: ' . $e->getMessage();        
    exit;   
     }
    print_r($requestCover);     // showing cover details on the screen  
    echo "<img src='".$requestCover['source']."'/>";
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type
>   Facebook\FacebookResponse as array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_app\twibook\index.php:165 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_app\twibook\index.php on line 165

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Facebook\FacebookResponse as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_app\twibook\index.php:165 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_app\twibook\index.php on line 165

Comment: I guess line 165 is the last line in your snippet? Try accessing it via `$requestCover->source`

Comment: yes exactly.... its the last line @Philipp

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Use `echo "<img src='".$requestCover->source."'/>";`

Comment: i tried but again error... ERRoR: Notice: Undefined property: Facebook\FacebookResponse::$source in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_app\twibook\index.php on line 165 @Philipp

Comment: When i tried in Graph Api Explorer tool ... its showing me the COVER by clicking on source ... The URL is: http://imgur.com/3gsssZm

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0#get-decoded-body

Comment: @Philipp I did what you said but it's not getting the index 'source'.. I'm badly stuck into this problem please help me out.

Comment: @CBroe If I was as smart as you that I can explore these docs then I will not be posting the problem on StackOverflow, no offence Boy: :)

Comment: @HassanKhan did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

CBroe is pointing you to the correct function to use, to get your data. I am using this answer as trying to explain what you should try doesn't fit well into the comments. (Haven't worked with this api yet, so I am not sure about the actual solution to your problem, but the description of handling your problem should be accurate)

---

By calling `$requestCover = $fb->get('me?fields=cover');` you are setting `$requestCover` to an object of class `FacebookResponse`.

Because it is an object, you can't access it's properties as you would when handling the elements of an array. You either have to use the `->`-operator to access them if they are public, or you have to use specific methods.

In this case, for the class `FacebookResponse`, there are methods you have to use. [The one CBroe pointed you to](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0#get-decoded-body), will return an array with the different data of the body of the response, so first write the return value of the call to this method on a variable and then you (should) have an array with your values.

```
try {   
    $requestCover = $fb->get('me?fields=cover'); //getting user Cover
     $requestProfileCover=$fb->get('/me');   
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo ' error: ' . $e->getMessage();         
    exit;   
}
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {            
    echo 'Facebook SDK error: ' . $e->getMessage();        
    exit;   
}
$responseBody = $requestCover->getDecodedBody();
echo "<img src='" . $responseBody ['source'] . "'/>";
print_r($requestCover); // should print an array
```